# How can i write application path with Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: c#, winforms, registry, setup-project

How can i write application installation path with Visual Studio Setup Project?

Comment: how can i write it while i setup the project with Visual Studio Setup Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is may discuss on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925216/getting-application-path-during-the-installation).