# how to set folder path that save in app config

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a windows application, Where one reporting folder . I want when user setup my application user can set reporting folder location and that will also save in my app.config file .  How can i do that ?

Comment: You can use User Settings instead of saving values in the app.config file. See [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: please re-read your question before posting. whilst grammatical problems are forgiven in SO, your question here is far from understandable

Comment: If you mean during installation see [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3925216/447356) then use Neil answer here to store the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the `Application.exe.config` you need to use `ConfigurationManager` class.
Here is a code sample:

```
// Open App.Config of executable
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
// Add an Application Setting.
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("UserReportPath");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("UserReportPath", txtUserReportPath.Text);
// Save the configuration file.
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
// Force a reload of a changed section.
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: @Neli Knight <add key="GlobalReportPath" value="D:\Projects\savanna\Source\NET\Savanna\Presentation\Savanna.UI.Windows\RDLC\GlobalSetting\"/> this is one of my report path . I want when user setup they can choose a path and that will save here ?