# How to force my dot net application to run as administrator just after installing msi?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I want to run my windows dot net application as administrator after just after installing msi .
Please help

Comment: Is the msi created by you? vs2010? and does your MSI require Administrative privileges?

Comment: Yes , MSI created by me in vs10 . but I want to run my programme automatically  after installing MSI as administrator

Comment: Just have your installer run your app immediately.  Since it runs elevated, your app will run elevated as well.  Do keep in mind that you have only one shot at it, if anything goes wrong or the user is too flabbergasted to do the right thing then the opportunity will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

If your MSI require Administrative privileges you can directly run your application as a new System.Diagnostics.Procesas by overriding the [Installer.OnAfterInstall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.configuration.install.installer.onafterinstall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Than the application will run under the same context.

If you have to force administrative context you can do it by the same way
Create an instance of the System.Diagnostics.Process class and set the Verb property to "runas".

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process.Verb = "runas";
```

If you need to know the installed location of your application take a look at this approach:
[Getting Application path during the installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925216/getting-application-path-during-the-installation)

**EDIT**

A approach is available on CodeProject:
[Launching Your Application After Install](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19560/Launching-Your-Application-After-Install-using-Vis)

Comment: Not working . I want to run application after installation as administrator

Comment: did you try System.Diagnostics.Process process.Verb = "runas"; ?